# Python: skip lines and split into columns text file

Tags: python, numpy, split, txt

I have a txt file, which looks like that:

---

Description
Description
0 0   170. 170.   40.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    18.09228
1 0   170. 170.  70.80 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    12.09736
....
1 0   170. 170.  06.48 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00    12.09736

---

I have tried to do this using:

```
data = np.loadtxt('Filename.txt', comments='#', delimiter=' ', skiprows=2)
```

But I get the error massage "could not convert string to float:" Probably it can occur because in the data there are different number of spaces between the columns.

Also I tried:

```
with open('Filename.txt') as f:  
   data = f.readlines()[2:]
```

But then I dont know how to split it into columns.
I just need an array with numbers after 'description' to make some computations.
I would really appreciate if someone could suggest a solution.

Comment: Could you describe how the output should look like?

Comment: `[line.split(" ") for line in data]` would this bring you closer to what you need.

Comment: I would bet that the issue is with the string (170.) this is not a number so np.load txt probably fails here.  Samusa posted would split your text into columns but you need to also manually fix all the numbers that dont end in a digit. i.e 170. -> 170.0

Comment: What is the expected output/behaviour?

Comment: I just want an array, which consist of these numbers to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If the file has values separated by a space you could do something like:

```
contents=[]
with open('Filename.txt') as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
     contents.append(line.rstrip().split(' '))
```

For skipping the first 2 columns:

```
contents=[]
with open('Filename.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    line=line.rstrip().split(' ')
    if len(line)<2:
      continue
    contents.append(line[2:])
```